# How to post a tweet using Codebird PHP from pop-up window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter, codebird

I am trying to allow visitors to my site to post a tweet with an image directly from the site. I am using [Codebird PHP library](https://github.com/jublonet/codebird-php) to accomplish this. So far everything is working correctly, however there is no preview of the post before it gets posted to the user's account. Currently, it just posts directly to their account as soon as they click the button.

What I would like is to have it pop-up a small window where it will ask them to log in if they aren't logged in yet, or it will show a preview of the tweet and allow them to click the "Tweet" button if they are logged in like in this image:

[image: sample tweet popup window]

Here's my PHP:

```
function tweet($message,$image) {
    require_once('codebird.php');
    \Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey("MYCONSUMERKEY", "MYCONSUMERSECRET");
    $cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
    session_start();

    if (! isset($_SESSION['oauth_token'])) {
      // get the request token
      $reply = $cb->oauth_requestToken([
        'oauth_callback' => 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
      ]);

      // store the token
      $cb->setToken($reply->oauth_token, $reply->oauth_token_secret);
      $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $reply->oauth_token;
      $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $reply->oauth_token_secret;
      $_SESSION['oauth_verify'] = true;

      // redirect to auth website
      $auth_url = $cb->oauth_authorize();
      header('Location: ' . $auth_url);
      die();

    } elseif (isset($_GET['oauth_verifier']) && isset($_SESSION['oauth_verify'])) {
      // verify the token
      $cb->setToken($_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
      unset($_SESSION['oauth_verify']);

      // get the access token
      $reply = $cb->oauth_accessToken([
        'oauth_verifier' => $_GET['oauth_verifier']
      ]);

      // store the token (which is different from the request token!)
      $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $reply->oauth_token;
      $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $reply->oauth_token_secret;

      // send to same URL, without oauth GET parameters
      header('Location: ' . basename(__FILE__));
      die();
    }

    // assign access token on each page load
    $cb->setToken($_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
    $reply = $cb->media_upload(array(
        'media' => $image
    ));
    $mediaID = $reply->media_id_string;
    $params = array(
        'status' => $message,
        'media_ids' => $mediaID
    );
    $reply = $cb->statuses_update($params);
}

tweet("Tweet tweet","assets/tweet.jpg");
```

And here's my Javascript/HTML:

```
function postTweet() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'tweet.php',
    data:{action:'call_this'},
    success:function(html) {
      alert('Success!');
    }
  });
}
<button class="download-share" onclick="postTweet()">Download and Share</button>
```

Comment: OK, and what's wrong with that code? Does it error out?

Comment: No, the code is fine, but it just posts the Tweet straight away when the user clicks the button. I want it to open a pop-up where it asks them to log in if they aren't logged in, or it shows a preview of the Tweet with a "Tweet" button(like in the image above) once they are logged in.

Comment: What part of that are you having difficulty with, then?

Comment: The part I am describing. Having the button open a pop-up window where the user is either asked to log in if they aren't already, or a preview of the tweet with a tweet button is shown so that the user can initiate the post themselves instead of it just posting immediately when they click the initial button.

Comment: OK, but that's just a `window.open` and a `<textarea>`. Take a stab at it.

Comment: It's not that simple. I have taken a stab at it and was unsuccessful, which is why I'm posting here.

Comment: It's mostly that simple. Give it a shot and let us know what specific issues you encounter that you need assistance with.

Comment: My issues are clearly defined in the question and the ensuing comments.

Comment: **it just posts the Tweet straight away when the user clicks the button. I want it to open a pop-up where it asks them to log in if they aren't logged in**... If they aren't logged in then how the tweet is getting posted??? its confusing

Comment: Essentially I want a pop-up window to open when the user clicks the button. If the user is already logged in to Twitter the pop-up will show the preview of the Tweet, if they aren't logged in the pop-up will show the login form and then show a preview of the Tweet once they've logged in. Basically, I want this to work exactly like the [web-intent](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent) functionality, but with the ability to attach an image.

Answer (score 3):

In the button click, you need another function that open the popup along with a tweet button.

Add the click event listener as `postTweet` to the new tweet button.

I created a sample snippet. Check it below.

To show the real time preview, you need to add the `keyup` event listener to the textarea which should copy it's value and add it as the `innerHTML` of the preview pane.

```js
function openTweet(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("preview")[0].style.display="";
    document.getElementById("tweetPr").innerHTML = document.getElementById("tweet").value;
    document.getElementById("tweet").addEventListener("keyup",
      function(){
          document.getElementById("tweetPr").innerHTML = document.getElementById("tweet").value;
      });
      document.getElementsByClassName("download-share")[0].style.display="none";
}

function postTweet() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'tweet.php',
    data:{action:'call_this'},
    success:function(html) {
      alert('Success!');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div style="display:none;" class="preview"><textarea id="tweet"> </textarea><div id="tweetPr"></div><button onclick="postTweet();">Tweet</button></div>
<button class="download-share" onclick="openTweet()">Download and Share</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

First things first, you(codebird) are using the twitter API to post to twitter, which makes use of the statuses/update endpoint in the API. This call is a server to server call, ie from the server where your files are hosted to the twitter server.
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update

There are 2 possibilities i see for you to accomplish what you have in mind

-first would be to use twitters web intent system with which you can send the tweet as a query string which would bring up the popup provided you have included the twitter js files
https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent

-second if thats not really your style then you could try something like what @ceejayoz mentioned making a new window created by you recreating the necessary inputs as shown in the picture and follow the same procedure you have now

Now to your question, Since you have an image the web intent option will not work, but if its a link with an image( twitter cards ) then i think the twitter bots should be able to read through the page and show you a preview in the popup provided you have the right meta tags on the linked page

Answer (score 0):

Try use the function `window.open`

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

```
function postTweet() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'tweet.php',
        data:{action:'call_this'},
        success:function() {
          success = true
        }
      });
      if(success)
      {
         window.open('tweet.php', "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400")
      }
}
```